# Third-party library inside dynamic feature module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I added third-party library into dynamic feature module and when building I'm receiving following error:

```
\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:375: AAPT: error: resource string
```

Only strings that are placed as `Activity's` labels in manifest in this third-party library are not found.

```
android:label="@string/
```

This behavior are reproducible only if I put third-party library into dynamic feature module. It works OK in simple android library module.

Also I've tried Clear/Rebuild project and nothing helps.

Comment: try Invalidate Cache / Restart once.

Comment: @AjayMehta-Rlogical already tried. doesn't help this

Answer (score -1):

See the 'Merged Manifest' for your 'AndroidManifest.xml' file by opening this manifest file in android studio and selecting 'Merged Manifest' option in footer. This might show the relevant information.